# ng2-translate fails on iOS device when trying to set language with NetworkError (DOM Exception 19): A network error occurred

Tags: ionic2, globalization

I have been trying to figure out why [Globalization.getPreferredLanguage()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/globalization/) would fail only when running on an iOS device (not when running on a simulator or Android device / emulator)

```
            Globalization.getPreferredLanguage().then((property) => {
                let lang = property.value;
                if (lang) {
                    if (lang.startsWith('en')){
                        this.translate.use('en_GB');                            
                    }
                    else if (lang.startsWith('fr')) {
                        this.translate.use('fr_FR');
                    }
                    else {
                        this.translate.use('en_GB');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("property.value is null");
                }
            }).catch((reason) => {
                this.translate.use('en_GB');// <-- not only does this NOT WORK, but the reason given is NetworkError (DOM Exception 19):  A network error occurred.                    
            });
```

What I have tried:

- Removing and adding the Globalization plugin with both ionic and cordova instructions:

> ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-globalization && ionic plugin add
>   cordova-plugin-globalization
>
> sudo cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-globalization && sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization

**EDIT 1**
So after more debugging I can see it is the angular ng2-translate 'use' function that is failing. In my app.module.ts:

```
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateStaticLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
...
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json');
}
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [Http]
        }),
        ...
    ]
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But in my app.component.ts when I call

```
this.translate.use('en_GB');
```

It throws some exception. I have checked and the files do exist in the folder:

> /.../platforms/ios/www/assets/i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, Globalization.getPreferredLanguage() is never resolved. So I am currently using

```
this.deviceLang = navigator.language;
```

This returns the device language with its variant like (FR-FR / EN-US)